# Instantiate an child object directly from a parent object

Tags: python, inheritance, instantiation

I have two objects one inherits from the other and the only difference between them is a few attribute fields:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self,a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def methodA(self):
        # do something
        pass

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self,c,**kwargs):
        self.c = c
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

I have an instance of the parent object and I want to find a fast way in python to create an instance of the child object which only has one additional field by using the already existing parent object.

Is there a python way or module that lets you do that easily. IN my real code the parent class has hundreds of fields and it is a bit inefficient to just reassign its value.

Comment: If you have parent object first and just need to sometimes add the additional field, I have two solutions: 1. have parent have the additional field always, and just assign it None by default, 2. duck-typing - instead of classes with different stuff, add attribute directly to the object you want (your type hinting might not like it)

Comment: @h4z3 yeah option (2) I thought but I dont want to mess up the typing. About option (1) I cant do that I dont manage that code but also i wouldn't like to do that cause the objects are used in different situations there is no pint having meaningless attributes in the parent object.

Comment: sounds like the real problem is having code that needs you to do this.  OOP design works best the other way around - create a more-specific instance (`Child`) and it is usable in all the places where you only need the less-specific instance (`Parent`) ... without having to create one from the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the other suggestions for making a method that takes in parent attributes and creates a child object is ok but adds unnecessary code I think. I made this solution, which I ended up using. It doesnt accept the parent object directly in as an argument but it is more concise I think:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self,c, **kwargs):
        self.c = c
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

# So if I start with this parent object
parent_args = {"a":23,"b":"iuhsdg"}
parent =Parent(**parent_args)

# I then make child with all the parent attributes plus some more
child_args = {"c":567}
child_args.update(vars(parent))
child = Child(**child_args)
```

Comment: Note that this only works if `Parent.__init__` simply takes its arguments and places their value in identically-named attributes. It breaks if `Parent` defines any attributes that are 1) not named exactly like its corresponding parameter in the `__init__` method (e.g. `self._a = a`), or 2) are derived from the parameters (e.g. `self.d = a + b`).

Comment: @jfaccioni yeah thats correct. But this is the case in this use case.

Answer (score 3):

The canonical solution is to add a class method to `Child` that works as a constructor. It takes a `Parent` instance and returns the `Child` instance with the proper attributes.

For example:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self,a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self,c,**kwargs):
        self.c = c
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def from_parent(cls, parent, c):
        return cls(a=parent.a, b=parent.b, c=c)


p = Parent(a=1, b=2)
c = Child.from_parent(parent=p, c=3)
print(c.a, c.b, c.c)  # output: 1 2 3
```

I would argue that your `Parent` class having hundreds of attributes is irrelevant to the answer. Yes, it's tedious having to explicitly write every attribute of the `Parent` instance in the `from_parent` method, but that's simply a limitation of having a class with that many attributes anyway. Possibly, a better design choice would be to encapsulate groups of `Parent` attributes into proper classes, so that only those instances need to be delivered to the `Child` class upon initialization.